# Resolution Matrix and data subsets

Tags: regression, least-squares, references, linear-model

If I solve a regularized linear least squares problem,
$$
\min_x || y - A x ||^2 + x^T \Lambda x
$$
then the solution is
$$
x^{est} = (A^T A + \Lambda)^{-1} A^T y
$$
Now the *resolution matrix* is the matrix relating the true model parameters $x^{true}$ to the estimated parameters $x^{est}$, by assuming that the observations $y$ can be written:
$$
y = A x^{true}
$$
so that
$$
x^{est} = (A^T A + \Lambda)^{-1} A^T A x^{true}
$$
and therefore the resolution matrix is:
$$
R = (A^T A + \Lambda)^{-1} A^T A
$$
**Question**

Now suppose I want to understand the resolution of the model parameters provided by *subsets* of the original observations. The motivation here is I want to know whether certain subsets of my data help to resolve certain model parameters or not. Suppose I partition my observation vector as
$$
y = \pmatrix{ y_1 \\ y_2 }
$$
and similarly,
$$
A = \pmatrix{A_1 \\ A_2}
$$
and I want to know how much model resolution is provided by $y_1$ and $y_2$ separately. My thinking is to follow exactly the same approach above, and say $y_i = A_i x^{true}$. Therefore, we have
\begin{align}
x^{est} &= (A^T A + \Lambda)^{-1} A^T \pmatrix{y_1 \\ 0} \\
&= (A^T A + \Lambda)^{-1} \pmatrix{A_1 \\ 0} x^{true}
\end{align}
so that we can write the resolution matrix of subset $i$ as:
$$
R_i = (A^T A + \Lambda)^{-1} A^T \pmatrix{ \vdots \\ A_i \\ \vdots }
$$
where the dots $\vdots$ indicate zeros. **Is this correct?**

I can imagine an alternative approach where I simply solve multiple least squares problems, one for each subset, and then define:
$$
R_i = (A_i^T A_i + \Lambda)^{-1} A_i^T A_i
$$

So which one of these approaches (if any) is the correct one?

As a side question, many texts discuss the resolution matrices, but I have not found a reference discussing this point of dividing up the data into subsets, so please provide a reference if you know of one.